# Notification for property changes in NSObject

Tags: ios, properties, nsnotificationcenter, key-value-coding

Is it possible to be notified for changes of all properties in an object? I would like to have a `selector` called whenever one of the properties in an NSObject is changed.

So far, I've only seen `keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:`, which isn't what I want, but it is persistent in showing up in my search results.

The specific objective that I currently have is to have a "FilterModel" that has properties for the specific filter characteristics. When any property is changed, I would like to update a `UITableView` with the newly filtered results.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13491454/key-value-observing-how-to-observe-all-the-properties-of-an-object

Comment: @StephenJ Thanks! Is that actually the best way of going about it, though? It seems quite hack-ey.

Comment: The solution in that answer is indeed hacky, if clever. One of its weaknesses is that it will only work for declared `@properties`. "Old" style properties with normally declared accessor methods, which are perfectly valid, and which emit KVO notifications automatically, will not be covered by that.

Comment: @RileyE Please post your solution as an Answer, instead of as part of the Question.

Comment: @AaronBrager Okay. Sorry about that. I didn't want to take away from the current answers that helped me get to this point.

Comment: You can add it as answer but leave the tick at the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to do that by querying the properties list of an object using Objective-C runtime and registering your custom class as an observer to them.

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>


//id yourObject;

unsigned int count;
objc_property_t* properties = class_copyPropertyList([yourObject class], &count);
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    const char* propertyName = property_getName(properties[i]);
    NSString *stringPropertyName = [NSString  stringWithCString:propertyName encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [yourObject addObserver:self forKeyPath:stringPropertyName options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
}
```

Also, don't forget to remove your custom class from the observer list before deallocation. Whenever a property changes, the called method is:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
```

Comment: Oh! This looks promising! I'm going to test it using a slightly different implementation.

Comment: Whenever a property changes, the called method is - (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context

Comment: Wow. This is actually amazing and perfect for what I'm looking for. Can you add that method to your answer?

Comment: KVO may sound good, but [I don't think you should use it](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/key-value-observing-done-right.html).

Comment: Hyperbole, you opened my world to a yet another awesome blog! Thank you. Also you look familiar, either you've moderated me or helped me in the past.

Comment: @Hyperbole, I think it's better to avoid such strong words as "I don`t think you should use it". KVO works well for some cases and there is no need to complicate things with third-party classes just because native tool is not perfect.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what you need one of these two options might be what you're looking for.

### KVO Observing

KVO Observing provides a framework for automatically listening on property changes without requiring modifications of getters and setters. Simply have to add your listening object as an observer or your target object via:

`addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:`

Then within your observer's implementation, implement:

`observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:`

and check if the path a notification was caught for matches your desired property. For more on receiving KVO notifications see [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002252-179866). For more details and a better visualization of the concept of KVO Observing see the [KVO Developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html).

### Manual NSNotifications

If you want to fine tune which changes you're interested in, whenever you make a change to your object of interest through the setter post a notification via:

`postNotificationName:object:userInfo:`

This will allow you to precisely customize what changes you're interested in, rather than hope for the exact behavior you're looking for from something like `keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:`. You can then catch these notifications by listening for your named notifications in your relevant views via:

`addObserver:selector:name:object:`

You can read more about posting notifications on the [NSNotificationCenter documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/postNotificationName%3aobject%3auserInfo%3a).

Comment: At that point, I may as well override the setter and perform the changes. I was hoping there was a way to have a model that can perform a trigger/notification whenever any component changes without having to override every individual property. It would be handy to have an iOS solution that can be applied in all similar cases.

Comment: hmm in that case have you looked into [KVO Observing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html)? That might be more along the lines of what you want.

Comment: Wouldn't that just be overriding the setters and getters?

Comment: The getters and setters of the property? I don't think so, you simply have to add your listening object as an observer or your target object via `addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:`. Then within your observer implement `observeValueForKeyPath` and check if the path a notification was caught for matches your desired property. There's a better visualization of KVO observing here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html

Comment: Okay. I misunderstood what you were referring to as I am new to KVC.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (id)init
{
    if(self = [super init])
    {
        unsigned int propertyCount;
        objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([self class], &propertyCount);
        for(int i = 0; i < propertyCount; i++)[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:[NSString stringWithCString:property_getName(properties[i]) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    unsigned int propertyCount;
    objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([self class], &propertyCount);
    for(int i = 0; i < propertyCount; i++)[self removeObserver:self forKeyPath:[NSString stringWithCString:property_getName(properties[i]) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    NSLog(@"Changed value at key path: %@", keyPath);
}
```